# Pairwise calculation on a 1D-Array with Matrix-like output

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assume you have the following 1D-Array:

`array([1,2,3,4,5])`

I want to perform different (simple) calculations between each combination of numbers (such as addition, subtraction, etc.) resulting in a Matrix-type output (without duplication), i.e. for the above array, the output should be as below if we wanted to calculated the pairwise difference:

```
array([0,-,-,-,-],            
      [1,0,-,-,-],
      [2,1,0,-,-],
      [3,2,1,0,-],
      [4,3,2,1,0])
```

Of course one could use brute force with two for loops but I feel like there is a better way, I just can't seem to find the right method.

Comment: So, for matrix output, what must be filled in the upper diagonal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of numpy broadcasting to calculate the pairwise difference. Like this no loops are needed. For that to happen the operation has to be done between a row- and a column-vector of the same array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,6, dtype=np.float)

# x[:,None] adds a second axis to the array
mat = x[:,None]-x
```

this yields:

```
array([[ 0., -1., -2., -3., -4.],
       [ 1.,  0., -1., -2., -3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0., -1., -2.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0., -1.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks. The matrix should be symmetric however, so the right side of the diagonal should also be positive.

Comment: You could just call `np.abs` on the resulting array.

Comment: yes, but I would want it to output the actual result on both sides of the diagonal. There might be mixed signs, which is when it gets tricky.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, I managed to find a solution using pairwise_distances from scikit-learn. This will by default just calculate the absolute distance between any pair, but it is possible to supply a custom function that takes two arguments, i.e. two numbers of a pair, for more elaborate calculations. It will require a slight reshape for 1D arrays.

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

def custom_calc(x,y):
    return (y-x)

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
matrix = pairwise_distances(a.reshape(-1,1), metric=custom_calc)
```

`matrix` will look as follows:

```
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
       [2., 1., 0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 2., 1., 0., 1.],
       [4., 3., 2., 1., 0.]])
```