# Pairwise Calculations on 1D Matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is basically the same as this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507877/pairwise-calculation-on-a-1d-array-with-matrix-like-output)
...and maybe it's exactly the answer I just don't understand the syntax of the np.arrange() function.

Here is what I am trying to do:

For each unique pair of values in a 1D array I want to calculate the ratio of max value to min value.
All the examples I can find, including the above mentioned, would indicate the np.arrange() function only works with sequential values i.e [1,2,3,4,5] and not from a unique array such as [1.34, 87.5, 2.10, 700.4]

max(0,1)/min(0,1) = (87.5/1.34)

max(0,2)/min(0,2) = (2.10/1.34)

Is the np.arrange() what I should be using or is there another function better suited to solving the problem?

Comment: `np.arange(3)`  is the same as `np.array([0,1,2])`.  Read its docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.arange()` has not been used to solve the problem, rather numpy broadcasting has been used to provide a solution in the link shared by you. `np.arange()` is used to create the initial array to work on (see [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)).

A simple solution to your problem would be using 2 loops like:

```
x = [1.34, 87.5, 2.10, 700.4]
mat = np.zeros(shape=(len(x),len(x)))
for i, ival in enumerate(x):
  for j, jval in enumerate(x):
    mat[i][j]=max(ival,jval)/min(ival,jval)
```

This yields the pairwise ratio of max to min:

```
 Result:
        [[  1.     65.299   1.567 522.687]
         [ 65.299   1.     41.667   8.005]
         [  1.567  41.667   1.    333.524]
         [522.687   8.005 333.524   1.   ]]
```

Comment: Cool... thanks for that explanation and the code example.  Seems I have a zero value in one of my cells throwing and a divide by zero error.  I need to add an if statement to work that out, but otherwise I think this will work.